# face='bold' of axis.text do not work and axis.line only control left and bottom in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, raster, r-raster, terra, rastervis

```
library(terra)
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- rast(f)
r
rr <- project(x=r,y='epsg:4326')
rr
gplot(rr)+
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value),na.rm=T)+
  scale_fill_distiller(na.value = NA)+
  ggtitle(label = 'Test')+
  coord_sf(crs=4326)+
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour='black', linewidth = 3, 
                                 linetype=1),
        axis.line.x.top = element_line(colour='black', linewidth = 1, 
                                       linetype=1),
        axis.line.y.right = element_line(colour='black', linewidth = 1, 
                                         linetype=1),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size = 20,
                                  face = 'bold',family = 'serif'),
        axis.text = element_text(size=20,face='bold',
                                   family = 'serif',color = 'black'),
        legend.title=element_text(face='bold',family = 'serif',
                                  size = 15),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15,
                                   face='bold',
                              family='serif'),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill=NA,color = 'black')
  )
```

[image]

I met this situation. I checked these codes many times, but the problem seemed still occured.

And I have tried tidyterra package as well. The same problem.

Ref:https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis/issues/96

Comment: Can you [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) the same issue using sample data? We can't access `external/test.grd`.

Comment: @jrcalabrese  Maybe you didn't install `raster` package? The test file is in `raster` package.

Comment: My fault! I was able to reproduce it after proper installation.